# Piecewise function is not correct plotted with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a piecewise function using the code below. The problem is, that the right piece is not plotted correct. It should (obviously) be constant zero, for values bigger than pi/2, but it does not look like that in the plot.
I am sure I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Plot]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= and(\x >= -pi, \x < -pi/2) * (0)   +
          and(\x >= -pi/2, \x <= pi/2) * (-(\x)*(\x)+pi*pi/4)     +
          and(\x > pi/2, \x <= pi) * * (0)
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
Axis Style,
xtick={
    -3.14159, -1.5708, 0,
    1.5708, 3.14159
},
xticklabels={
    $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$
},
ytick={
    0,
    1.234, 2.467
},
yticklabels={
    $0$, $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$, $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$
},
samples=75
]
\addplot [mark=none,ultra thick, domain=-3.1415:3.15, blue] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Without testing it I would guess that this is because of the number of samples and where they are. Remove `mark=none` to confirm this. Then you can either increase the number of samples by adding `samples=<number of samples` to either the `axis` or the `\addplot` options or make sure that there is a sample point at all relevant places.

Comment: I have already tried increasing/decreasing the number of samples, it sometimes got better, but a higher number of samples did not mean a better result...

Comment: Removing mark=none had no effect

Comment: I haven't tested but I think that removing a `*` in the third line in `declare function` would do.

Comment: Both of the first two lines have one `*` each, but the third one has two `*`s. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I wonder how I could not have noticed that..

Comment: @frankenapps You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a small mistake in your code.
Try with this small change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= and(\x >= -pi, \x < -pi/2) * (0)   +
          and(\x >= -pi/2, \x <= pi/2) * (-(\x)*(\x)+pi*pi/4)     +
          and(\x > pi/2, \x <= pi)  * (0)
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
Axis Style,
xtick={
    -3.14159, -1.5708, 0,
    1.5708, 3.14159
},
xticklabels={
    $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$
},
ytick={
    0,
    1.234, 2.467
},
yticklabels={
    $0$, $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$, $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$
},
samples=75
]
\addplot [mark=none,ultra thick, domain=-3.1415:3.15, blue] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Axis Style,` is not defined ...